# Amazon echo voice command to trigger computer on/off

Tags: java

https://www.reddit.com/r/amazonecho/comments/4wlpgt/alexa_turn_on_my_computer_anyone_have_a_setup/

https://www.reddit.com/r/amazonecho/comments/3dk07k/can_i_turn_onoff_my_computer_with_echo/

These to links show questions and answer upon how to make a switch for an amazon echo dot to turn on/off a computer with a voice command. I see that these posts are 5+ months old and figured it would maybe be an easier solution now for this. I have a raspberry pi with a plexgear controller for it. I wonder if I can use this to program the pi to trigger the computer, then pair the controller with the echo dot or something like that. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it only all the devices connected to the same network. Check it at [Amazon Echo Dot](https://thebeter.com/amazon-echo-dot)